# Perfecting a regex pattern

Tags: regex

On the MUD I play, mob room descriptions can start in many variations. I'm attempting to write a regex to where it only captures the mob's room description, and not any of the possible beginning flags. This is what I have so far:

```
^\((?:[ACDGHIXRSTUW()]+|\s?\(Angry\))\)?\s?(.*)$
```

It works, for the most part, until the mob does not have a starting flag. Here's an example of what I'm talking about regarding variations:

```
(H) (Angry) A mob is here.
(A)(W)(R) A mob is also here.
Another mob is here.
```

That's just three different ways a mob could appear. Essentially, every letter in the range portion can be a flag, surrounded by (). On single letter flags, there are no spaces between ) and the next (. However, there is a space before (Angry), except when it leads.

My issue is that it's not capturing the last mob, and it's capturing "(Angry)" in the first mob. I have a fair grasp of regex in general, I think, but I can't see what I'm doing incorrectly, and it may not even be the most efficient way to handle it.

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, I just want to capture everything after the last ), or from the start if there are no flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
^(?:.*\))?(.*)
```

Comment: Actually, I originally went with hwnd's answer, but found Avinash Raj's version (with a small modification) to work better! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
^(?>.*\))?\s*(.*)
```

Comment: Yours worked, it didn't seem to like the new line $ stopping it, so it bled into the next line. Not sure what caused it, but this actually helped me for future regex, too!

Answer (score 1):

or use this pattern
`\s*([^)]+$)` or in multi line input `\s*([^)\r\n]+$)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/38)

```
\s*                      whitespace (0 or more times)
(                        group capture
  [^)]+                  any character except: ')' (1 or more times)
  $                      before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)                        end of group
```